# Need help writing a function to return an empty array if key doesn't exist as a within objects inside of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, shopify, gatsby

I'm working on a headless Shopify app in Gatsby/React. I need some help working with the data I get back from Shopify.

Here is an example of what the data looks like:

```
product.options = [
  {
    name: 'Size',
    values: ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL'],
  },
  {
    name: 'Colour',
    values: ['Terrazzo Berry'],
  },
];
```

I want to create a variable of value key for the colours.

```
const colours =
    product.options.find((option) => option.name.toLowerCase() === 'colour')
      .values || [];
```

The only problem is, if there is no key in the object called colours I get the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'product.options.find(function (option) {
    return option.name.toLowerCase() === 'colour';
  }).values')
```

Can someone help me write some code that returns an empty object if the key I'm searching for doesn't exist

Comment: just a note, if successful your code does not create a new array but uses the same

Comment: I ended up making a slight change using the new optional chaining method.

`const colours =
    product.options.find((option) => option.name.toLowerCase() === 'colour')
        ?.values || [];`

Comment: it can't never work with this way,, array find return a pointer on array element, not a copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set default value before accessing `.values` key

```
const colours =
    (product.options.find((option) => option.name.toLowerCase() === 'colour')
      || {values: []}).values;

      // ^^^^^^^^^^^^
      // You can use whatever value you want, i've use array as default value
```

**What is problem with my code ?**

In your code if the key is not found `find` function returns `undefined` and the you have `.values` property access, so you endup with an error